# Como fazer Regex que aceite somente números?

Tags: php, regex

Como faço para usar o `preg_match` que só aceite números? E que esses números possam começar também com zero?

```
function formatacao_cpf_func(){

    $regular = "/^[0-9]*$/";

    if(preg_match($regular, $this->cpf)){

    if(!is_numeric($this->cpf)){
        echo "O campo CPF só poderá conter Números";
        die;
    }

    if(strlen($this->cpf) > 11 || strlen($this->cpf) < 11 ){
        echo "Por favor informe o CPF com 11 digitos Válidos";
        $tamanho = strlen($this->cpf);
        echo $tamanho;
        die;
    }

    if(strlen($this->cpf) == 11){
       echo "CPF foi digitado corretamente </br>";
       $formatando_cpf_func = substr($this->cpf, 0, 3) . '.' . substr($this->cpf, 3, 3) . 
            '.' . substr($this->cpf, 6, 3) . '-' . substr($this->cpf, 9, 2);
       echo $formatando_cpf_func;
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `^[0-9]*$`?

Comment: tentei desta forma e não deu certo           $regular = "/^[0-9]+$/";

Comment: E qual é o conteúdo da *string* e qual é o resultado esperado? Coloque isso junto com o seu código na pergunta, utilizando o botão [edit].

Comment: Aparentemente funciona, veja este teste: https://ideone.com/IglogT.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) para verificar se string contém apenas números. [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) aceita números fracionados, negativos e sinal de mais.

```
var_dump(is_numeric(-1.33)); //true
var_dump(is_numeric(+1.33)); //true
```

Mude:

```
$regular = "/^[0-9]*$/";
if(preg_match($regular, $this->cpf)){

if(!is_numeric($this->cpf)){
    echo "O campo CPF só poderá conter Números";
    die;
}
```

Para:

```
if(!ctype_digit("$this->cpf")){
   echo "O campo CPF só poderá conter Números";
   die;
}
```

Se realmente deseja usar regex, pode usar `#^\d{11}$#` que diz que a string deve ter exatamente onze dígitos.

É possível refatorar essa função para:

```
function formatacao_cpf_func(){

    $tamanhoCPF = strlen($this->cpf);

    if(!ctype_digit("$this->cpf") || $tamanhoCPF != 11) die('O campo CPF é inválido');


    echo "CPF foi digitado corretamente </br>";
    $arr = str_split($str, 3);
    printf('%s.%s.%s-%s', ...$arr);
}
```

Basicamente onde tinham dois if, agora as condições foram juntadas para dizer se a entrada (cpf) é valida ou não.

A maneira como é formatado o cpf mudou primeiro a string é convertida em um array separado por três caracateres cada elemento ou seja são quatro elementos de com comprimento de 3 e o último como 2.

[`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) ou [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) montam uma mascará baseado no formato. Lembrando que o [operador `...` (ellipsis)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) só funciona do php5.6 para frente em versões anteriores  é necessário especificar os índices do array ou usar a função [`vprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php).

Na versão regex o tamanho já é validado junto com os caracteres númericos.

```
function formatacao_cpf_func($cpf){

    $regex = '#^\d{11}$#';
    if(!preg_match($regex, $cpf)) die('O campo CPF é inválido');

    echo "CPF foi digitado corretamente </br>";
    $arr = str_split($cpf, 3);
    printf('%s.%s.%s-%s', ...$arr);
}
```

Comment: Tem algum problema na resposta?

Comment: O pessoal daqui é exigente kkk, talvez seja por que ele queira um REGEX e sua resposta não resolveu o problema da forma que ele queria.

Comment: @GuilhermeBiancardi, eu particularmente não vi o como essa resposta está de qualidade ruim. O uso de regex para este caso pode ser um sinal de se [usar um tanque de guerra para abrir cocos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6585/64969)... então respostas alternativas que não utilizem tanques de guerra deveriam ser aceitas. Afinal, essa pergunta em específico não indicou ser uma espécie de `code-golf` para se programar dentro de parâmetros restritos de programação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Só estou dizendo o que eu acho... se eu preciso de um REGEX por exemplo por que vou usar "is_numeric()" pelo o que eu sei 000.000.000-00 retornaria false... já com o REGEX... E não acho que o REGEX seja um tanque de guerra abrindo um coco... se o cara usasse um "explode()" com um "for()" aí sim diria que ele esta usando um tanque de guerra para abrir um coco.

Comment: @GuilhermeBiancardi não precisa de regex para resolver esse problema mas se quiser pode usar :)

Comment: @rray, ratificando esse seu último comentário: eu usaria regex por vício, eu vivo injetando café e regex na veia. Mas sei que ela é uma solução _overkill_ para esse caso, dado o input.

Comment: internamente o `ctype_digit` não seria um `for` percorrendo cada caractere? Creio que não teria muita diferença entre o motor da regex apresentada e o `ctype`. cc @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu não sei como funciona o `ctype_digit()` internamente :P. Pelo menos nos teste que fiz [ctype](https://3v4l.org/Z2ttC/perf#output) e [regex](https://3v4l.org/kRgMp/perf#output) o `ctype_` foi ligeiramente melhor.

Comment: @rray interessante, e ate entendo essa pequena diferença.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert a vantagem da regex mesmo é validar os dois critérios ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $regular = "#^\d+$#";

 if(preg_match($regular, $this->cpf)){
   // somente numero;

   if(strlen($this->cpf) == 11){
     // Uma ajuda extra com regEx para formatar o cpf
     $formatando_cpf_func = preg_replace("#(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})#", "$1.$2.$3-$4", $this->cpf);
     echo "CPF foi digitado corretamente </br> $formatando_cpf_func";
   } else {
     echo "Por favor informe o CPF com 11 digitos Válidos";
     $tamanho = strlen($this->cpf);
     echo $tamanho;
     die;
   }
 } else {
   // if(!is_numeric($this->cpf)) <-- remover essa validação, não é necessária, já que foi feita com regex
   echo "O campo CPF só poderá conter Números";
   die;
 }
```

Comment: Poderia explicar, com texto, a sua solução, deixando claro quais são as diferenças entre o seu código e o da pergunta e quais eram os problemas do código do AP?